# Ruby Error: private method `execute' called

Tags: ruby

Edit: To save confusion, I've added the actual code I'm having the issue with instead of the example. Same error as before. This is an interactive shell, and for example if I type ls -a it attempts to call the 'execute' method, but instead crashes saying that the method is private. I don't understand how it's private, nor how to work around this.

```
$ ruby shell.rb 
ls -a
Traceback (most recent call last):
        3: from shell.rb:59:in `<main>'
        2: from shell.rb:6:in `main'
        1: from shell.rb:6:in `loop'
shell.rb:10:in `block in main': private method `execute' called for #<Command:0x00005637cb75b1e8 @args=["ls"@0, "-a"@3]> (NoMethodError)
```

Ruby Code:

```
require 'readline'
require 'parslet'

def main
  loop do
    cmdline = Readline.readline("> ", true) 
    #  p tree
    tree.execute
  end
end

def parse_cmdline(cmdline)
  raw_tree = Parser.new.parse(cmdline)
  Transform.new.apply(raw_tree)
end

class Parser < Parslet::Parser
  root :cmdline 

  rule(:cmdline) { command }
   
  rule(:command) { arg.as(:arg).repeat(1).as(:command) }
  rule(:arg) { match[%q{^\s}].repeat(1) >> space? }

  rule(:space?) {space.maybe }     
  rule(:space) { match[%q{\s}].repeat(1).ignore }
end

class Transform < Parslet::Transform
    rule(command: sequence(:args)) { Command.new(args) } #ls
    rule(arg: simple(:arg)) { arg } # -a   
end


class Command
  def initialize(args)
    @args = args
  end
end


def execute
  spawn(*@args)
end

main
```

Comment: Please, do not change your question in a way that invalidates existing answers. That is considered to be very rude because it nullifies all the hard work that the answerers have put into their answers, especially since none of us get paid to, essentially, do your work for you. It also makes answerers look like idiots, unless you carefully inspect the question history and compare the timestamps of the edits and the answers. If you want to clarify something, edit it into your question in such a way that it does not fundamentally change the question and does not invalidate any answers.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think about that. I'm rather new here. I'll keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 1):

#### Why it doesn't work?

`tree = (3) # tree is an integer`

`tree.execute # integers don't have an execute method`

It's unclear what you are trying to do?

#### Try this instead:

I think you are trying to create a tree class? It's hard to say.

```
class Tree
  def initialize(tree)
    @tree = tree
  end

  def execute
    puts @tree
  end
end

def test
  loop do
    tree = Tree.new(3)
    tree.execute
  end
end

test
```

Because you are doing an infinite loop, you'll have to press: "CTRL + C" to kill the program, when you want it to stop (That'll work for Ubuntu, but not sure how it will work with other linux based distros or macs or windows).

Comment: I edited my original post to better reflect what I'm trying to to. It's an interactive shell and when I attempt to use a command, the execute method gets called, but because it's private the program crashes. I don't understand how the execute method is private, nor how to work around this...

Comment: @MichaelBaca perhaps you are new to stack overflow?  Consider writing a completely new question if you're changing things materially.